# Difference between「湿る」「濡れる」

Tags: word-choice, meaning, words

Could you help me to understand the difference between「湿る」「濡れる」?

Comment: Basically, 濡れる > 湿る

Comment: Damp vs wet basically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

湿る is different from 濡れる. 湿る means "damp" or "moisted." 濡れる means "get wet / soaked (with water)."

In this rainy season, air circulating in your room would be 湿っぽい - humid and moisty. You'll get wet with rain -　雨で濡れる　when you walk out without carrying an umbrella.